# Dependency Injection: passing a model between controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

A question about dependency injection: I understand the idea of initialising a controller with a pointer to a data model when the controller is created:

```
Controller *controller = [[Controller alloc] initWithDataModel:[self dataModel]];
```

But I was curious to read an answer on here by TechZen that mentioned passing a model between controllers.

> TechZen "Dependency Injection relies
>   on passing the data model object from
>   view controller to view controller as
>   needed."
>   [Cocoa touch connection and data design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381910/cocoa-touch-connection-and-data-design-pattern)

Does this simply refer to the fact that each controller is initialised with a pointer on creation, or is it referring to assigning / swapping the data model at a later date maybe using a pointer to the new model passed in via a method?

```
- (void)connectToModel:(id)newModel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote is not really clear to me, but the basic principle of Dependency Injection is that the controllers *get the model provided by somebody else* (= injected), they do not seek it themselves. The model may be supplied when the controller gets created (in the initializer) or it may be supplied later, through a setter. Both scenarios are equal as far as the basic idea of DI goes.

Comment: Thanks Zoul, thats what I was after, I just wanted to make sure I was understanding the concept. Much appreciated ...